# How do I drop a subscript in sympy?

Tags: sympy

In sympy vectors, as in:

```
import sympy.vector as vs
sp.init_printing()
c = vs.CoordSys3D('c', transformation='cylindrical', variable_names=("r", "t", "z"))
vs.gradient(c.t)
```

the output of any computation such as `vs.gradient(c.t)` is ridden with subscripts as in:

$$\frac{1}{r_c}\hat{j}_{c}$$

Is there a way to drop the subscript 'c' from all subsequent calculation? It is hard to read and I do not intend to change the coordinates again. I have performed some nasty calculation. It would be easier to understand if I could drop the 'c' throughout.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

```
 c = vs.CoordSys3D('', transformation='cylindrical', variable_names=("r", "t", "z"))
```

note, I just had to give an empty string '' instead of 'c'